# Why are KMeans cluster labels not always the same with set random_state?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a notebook where I want to analyze the clusters from `sklearn.cluster.KMeans`. When I run the code, the clusters are the same, but the labels applied can vary. This makes it impossible for me to refer to a cluster by label in the markdown sections of the notebook. I am wondering why this occurs even when setting the `random_state`. It appears that `random_state` is only allowing for the clustering to be the same, but why does it not also apply the same label values each time? The code below will replicate the issue and the plot shows how the labels can vary.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2)

x = np.random.normal(size=(1800, 2))
x[:700, 0] += 3
x[:700, 1] += 3
x[700:1200, 0] -= 0.5
x[700:1200, 1] -= 0.5
x[1200:, 0] += 3
x[1200:, 1] -= 3

np.random.shuffle(x)

first = None
while True: # it typically only takes a few iterations for a difference to occur
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=10)
    km.fit(x)
    pred = km.predict(x)
    if first is None:
        first = pred
    elif not np.array_equal(first, pred):
        print(first)
        print(pred)
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
        for label in range(3):
            clusters = x[first == label]
            cluster = x[pred == label]
            ax[0].scatter(clusters[:, 0], clusters[:, 1], label=label)
            ax[1].scatter(cluster[:, 0], cluster[:, 1], label=label)
        break

ax[0].legend()
ax[1].legend()
plt.show()
```

```
[0 1 1 ... 2 0 0] # labels for first run
[0 2 2 ... 1 0 0] # different labels for later run
```

[image: kmeans plot difference]

Furthermore, I am confused as to why the verbose output is not exactly the same when using the same `random_state`.

I have noticed a couple of things. First is that `np.random.seed(1)` will not generate this problem. So, it appears to be data-dependent. Second if `n_jobs=1` this doesn't seem to occur but the default `n_jobs=None` gives different results (both labels and verbose output). Is the parallelization causing this to happen?

It would be good to know if this is a bug that I should report to scikit-learn devs or if this is a an issue specific to my case that will require a work-around.

Comment: This [article](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224759/how-to-avoid-k-means-assigning-different-labels-on-different-run) says that this behavior is intentional but has workarounds if you need to fix it.

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe Yes, but that article does not set the random_state so the explanation is that it is because cluster centers are distributed randomly. It is my understanding that the cluster centers should be initialized to the same values when random_state is set.

Comment: Here is the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/6850c04186b88e88e9c8cd6eb673721af806e3da/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py#L678) which might help you to answer the question of *why*.

Comment: @Kraigolas I have thoroughly read through the source code. The only use of randomness is the cluster center initialization, so I don't understand the varying result. The backends are written using Cython, is it possible some alternate random state is introduced by the C code?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is due to rounding errors. The best labels are updated anytime the current inertia is better than the previous best. However, due to rounding errors, an inertia value may be equal to the current value but appear slightly better and update the labels unnecessarily. There is currently a [PR](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/20200) that is addressing this issue.